# Isolated point in a subset

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, baire-category

Let $(X,d)$ a metric space. Let $A$ be a subset of $X$. A point $a\in A$ is isolated if only if there is $r>0$ such that $B(a,r)\cap A=\{a\}$. Let $a\in A$ be. I am trying to prove that
$$\operatorname{int}(\{a\})=\emptyset\iff a \text{ is not isolated in }A \tag{1}$$
If $a$ is not isolated in A, then is easy verify that $\operatorname{int}(\{a\})=\emptyset$. But the other hand is dificult for me and I don't know if (1) is true. Thank you so much!

Comment: How do you define $\operatorname{int}(A)$?

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly false. Take $X=\Bbb R$ in the usual metric and $A=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ and $a=2$.

Note that the set $A$ is irrelevant in the statement $\operatorname{int}(\{a\}) = \emptyset$.